# angular use [ng-if] on select with options

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I am using angular 1.5 and I am trying to use some logic for data I got back from the microsoft graph which is totally dynamic (key and value) and create a dropdown list. I go it working with a input box, but cannot seem to get it working with a select box.

The input box that works

```
<input type="text" name="{{prop.name}}" ng-model="vm.filterValues[prop.name]">
    <div ng-repeat="uniqueValue in vm.schemaExtentionsUniqueValues">
         <div ng-if="uniqueValue[0] == prop.internalName || uniqueValue[0] == prop.name">
              {{uniqueValue[1]}}
         </div>
    </div>
```

The select box I was trying to build with sementic errors that is not working:

```
 <select name="{{prop.name}}" ng-model="vm.filterValues[prop.name]">
    <span ng-repeat="uniqueValue in vm.schemaExtentionsUniqueValues">
          <span ng-if="uniqueValue[0] == prop.internalName || uniqueValue[0] == prop.name">
              <option value="{{uniqueValue[1]}}">{{uniqueValue[1]}}</option>
          </span>
    </span>
 </select>
```

The data 
[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Cheers!

The value the first item in each array entry gets checked against a dynamic property.

Comment: Please post data example or create demo in Fiddler or plunkr

Comment: Can't you simply [filter:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) your ng-repeat list?

Comment: Is it possible to check a filter value against another property which is not from this array?

Comment: You can `filter:` against anything in scope - `prop.internalName` and `prop.name` are for sure in your case. @rrd has a point suggesting filtering as early as possible, but in this specific case I'd argue a `filter:` is *clean* enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving a lot of your logic into your controller. This makes the template 'clean' and places the code where it is more easily accessible in one place.

This would basically mean filtering/sorting the *schemaExtentionsUniqueValues* before it gets to the template to be displayed.

```
schemeExtentionsUniqueValues(propName) {
  // Filter this based on propName passed in;
}
```

The second span can be put into the option btw:

```
<select name="{{prop.name}}" ng-model="vm.filterValues[prop.name]">
  <span ng-repeat="uniqueValue in vm.schemaExtentionsUniqueValues(prop.name)">
    <option ng-if="uniqueValue[0] == prop.internalName || uniqueValue[0] == prop.name"
      value="{{uniqueValue[1]}}">{{uniqueValue[1]}}</option>
  </span>
</select>
```

If you use your controller to determine what is inside *schemaExtentionsUniqueValues* then you probably won't need the ng-if on the option tag, and can just display as you would normally.

Comment: I usually would do this but the value of [prop.internalName] is only set in the for loop in the view. This has to do with injecting html otherwise i would have to use $sce.

Comment: I've altered it slightly to add in argument, and fleshed out the schema..